# How to separate string by ' ' and store in two dimensional array in java

Tags: java

How to separate following string by ' ' and store in two dimensional array in java

"('1494576','16268568','5150022241','Flour','Pillsbury','2 For $5.00','5','8/20/2016','80','Best All Purpose Unbleached Enriched','Demoulas/Market Basket','2','itemlink')"

I need data only in between ' ' in two dimensional array
like
temp[0][0]="1494576"
temp[0][1]="16268568"

Comment: Separate by what? A space? An empty string? Literally two single quotes?

Comment: Could you please make this legible? I have no idea what you are trying to say although I think I have an idea.

Comment: If you converted `(` and `)` to `[` and `]`, you could probably get away with just using a JSON parser library and it would build the (one-dimensional) array for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

As @Jesse Amano recommends, you could probably get away with using JSON. Here's another crude way of doing it:

```
    String s = "('1494576','16268568','5150022241','Flour','Pillsbury','2 For $5.00','5','8/20/2016','80','Best All Purpose Unbleached Enriched','Demoulas/Market Basket','2','itemlink')";
    String[][] temp = ...;
    boolean inside = false;
    boolean end = false;
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i ++){
        if(s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("'")){
            inside = !inside; //determines if we are between ''
            if(end) index ++;
            end = !end; //determines if this is the closing '
        }
        else{
            if(inside) temp[0][index] += s.substring(i, i +1);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "('1494576','16268568','5150022241','Flour','Pillsbury','2 For $5.00','5','8/20/2016','80','Best All Purpose Unbleached Enriched','Demoulas/Market Basket','2','itemlink')"
s  = s.substring(2,s.length()-2);
String[] str = s.split("','");
String[][] temp = new String[3][4];
int k = 0;
for(String[] a: temp){
    for(String b: a){
        b = str[k];
        k++;
    }
}
```

Since you have 13 elements, it's not possible to put it in rectangular 2D array. This one will hold only 12 of them. You may adjust your data or use jagged array to hold just 13.

Comment: This breaks as soon as there can be a comma in the actual data.

Comment: Thanks..corrected my answer. But this one also breaks if there is ',' in the data which I hope not to be.